# Tips to better remember Pascal's identity?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Does anyone have tips on how to better remember Pascal's identity? Ideally, I want to be able to recall it and the intuition quickly.

Comment: You can pick a team of $k$ by deciding that Draco Malfoy will definitely be in the team, and choosing his $k-1$ teammates, or by deciding Draco will definitely *not* be in the team, and choosing the $k$ members from among everyone else. So $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$.

Comment: You can remember it by remembering how to build Pascal's Triangle (each entry being the sum of the two above it.)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.